# R Language NaN + NA behaviour

Tags: r, nan, na

I have a question about arithmetic behaviour in R.
Regard the following piece of code

```
> NaN + NA
[1] NaN
>
>
> NaN + as.integer(NA)
> NA
```

So, I am confused that these two additions give different results.
Does anybody know if this is really wanted behaviour or just some kind of bug?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is interesting! Which version of R do you use? I have 2.14.1 on Linux, Ubuntu.

Comment: I get `> NaN + NA [1] NaN`.  Linux, R2.15.0.

Comment: @ttmaccer Your comments seems like it answers the question. Perhaps you want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From `?NaN`:

> Computations involving `NaN` will return `NaN` or perhaps `NA`: which of those two is not guaranteed and may depend on the R platform (since compilers may re-order computations).