# Addition of NA and expression that evaluates to NaN return different results depending on order, violation of the commutative property?

Tags: r, commutativity

I am investigating corner cases of numeric operations in R. I came across the following particular case involving zero divided by zero:

```r
(0/0)+NA
#> [1] NaN
NA+(0/0)
#> [1] NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Big Sur 10.16
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] digest_0.6.27     withr_2.4.2       magrittr_2.0.1    reprex_2.0.0     
#>  [5] evaluate_0.14     highr_0.9         stringi_1.6.2     rlang_0.4.11     
#>  [9] cli_3.0.0         rstudioapi_0.13   fs_1.5.0          rmarkdown_2.9    
#> [13] tools_4.1.0       stringr_1.4.0     glue_1.4.2        xfun_0.23        
#> [17] yaml_2.2.1        compiler_4.1.0    htmltools_0.5.1.1 knitr_1.33
```

This clearly violates the commutative property of addition. I have two questions:

1. Is there an explanation of this behavior based on the R language definition?
2. Are there other examples of the violation of the commutative property of addition (including in other languages) that don't involve side effects in the addend sub-expressions?

Comment: More explicit in `?NaN`: "Computations involving `NaN` will return `NaN` or perhaps `NA`: which of those two is not guaranteed and may depend on the R platform (since compilers may re-order computations)."

Comment: Related `NaN` confusion (seemingly platform dependent): [R Language NaN + NA behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328938/r-language-nan-na-behaviour)

Answer (score 12):

Noting that

```
0/0
#[1] NaN
```

a more general example of the behavior of `+` in the question is the following:

```
NA + NaN
#[1] NA
 
NaN + NA
#[1] NaN
```

This is in a [r-devel thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2018-July/076381.html) and R Core Team member [Tomas Kalibera answers the following](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2018-July/076453.html) (my emphasis and link).

> Yes, the performance overhead of fixing this at R level would be too
> large and it would complicate the code significantly. **The result of
> binary operations involving NA and NaN is hardware dependent** (the
> propagation of NaN payload) - on some hardware, it actually works the
> way we would like - NA is returned - but on some hardware you get NaN or
> sometimes NA and sometimes NaN. Also there are C compiler optimizations
> re-ordering code, as mentioned in ?NaN. Then there are also external
> numerical libraries that do not distinguish NA from NaN (NA is an R
> concept). **So I am afraid this is unfixable.** The [disclaimer mentioned by
> Duncan](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2018-July/076380.html) is in ?NaN/?NA, which I think is ok - there are so many numerical
> functions through which one might run into these problems that it would
> be infeasible to document them all. **Some functions in fact will preserve
> NA, and we would not let NA turn into NaN unnecessarily, but the
> disclaimer says it is something not to depend on.**

Comment: Another relevant R-help thread, just for completeness: [noncommutative addition: NA+NaN != NaN+NA](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-September/057043.html)

Answer (score 7):

According to `?NA`, this could be because of `NaN` resulted from `0/0`

> Numerical computations using NA will normally result in NA: a possible exception is where NaN is also involved, in which case either might result (which may depend on the R platform). However, this is not guaranteed and future CPUs and/or compilers may behave differently. Dynamic binary translation may also impact this behavior (with valgrind, computations using NA may result in NaN even when no NaN is involved).

Comment: Also relevant, this [R-Help post](https://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg249643.html). And I remember seeing others. Yes, in [r-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2018-July/076381.html).